# Sum of quoted premium using a subquery

Tags: mysql, pivot, mysql-workbench

I want to calculate the sum of quoted premium for all the quote numbers present in the table with the latest transaction based on trans_id. The below query works for a single quote number, where the order by Transaction_id DESC limit 1 gives the highest transaction record.

```
SELECT  SUM(quoted_premium)  FROM policy 
     Where  quote_no= '1010'
     AND trans_type IN ('quote1','new', 'quote2')
     group by quote_no,Trans_id
     ORDER BY Trans_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Since the data is confidential, I'll give a sample table. There are multiple records for same quote no but different transaction id. I need to get the sum of a bunch of transaction id with recent records. The above query works fine for one quote number, but not for sum of all.

```
Trans_id    quote_no    trans_type  quoted premium  
1              1011         quote2      0   
1              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2     -16  
2              1010         quote2     -19  
2              1010         quote2     -51  
2              1010         quote2     776  
2              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2     381  
2              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2      59  
2              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2      0   
2              1010         quote2      9   
2              1010         quote2     194  
2              1010         quote2      0   
3              1010         quote2      0   
3              1010         quote2      0   
3              1010         quote2      1   
.               .             .         .
.               .             .         .
.               .             .         .
```

I need to match the above records to this below csv file. The total number of records present in the csv file are 39731

```
QUOTE_NO  New   Quote1   Quote2     GrandSum
1009     1425     -         -        1,425   
1010       -      0        556         556
1111       -      0       1,332      1,332       
.          .      .         .           .
.          .      .         .           .
                             sum     54,138,664
                             Avg     1363
```

So, when I use the above query to calculate the sum of quoted premium for quote no: 1010 it gives me the value 556. Similarly when I try to remove the condition for quote number and try to run the query it gives me a value of some quote number which had the latest transaction record.

I want to use subquery and do a self join to get the proper result, but I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Your question asks *batch of transaction id with recent records.*.  Please [edit] your question to tell us what you mean by *recent records.* Are they the ones with the highest `trans_id` values?

Comment: @O.Jones The batch of transaction id means, a bunch of transaction id. For eg in the above table, I need quoted premium where transaction id = 2. And yes, 
 the sum of quoted premium for highest trans_id's for every quote number is to be found, which should give only a single value, summing all the values of quoted premium

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Although, I would do this in the application code layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a result set considering only the highest `Trans_id` for each `quote_no`. That's what you mean by *most recent.* Start with a subquery to get those `Trans_id` values. 
 [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

```
SELECT quote_no, MAX(Trans_id) Trans_id
  FROM policy
 GROUP BY quote_no;

| quote_no | Trans_id |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1010     | 3        |
| 1011     | 1        |
```

Next, you should write a query to fetch the `GrandSum` values, to convince yourself you have done your filtering correctly.

```
SELECT p.quote_no, SUM(p.quoted_premium) GrandSum
  FROM policy p
  JOIN (
             SELECT quote_no, MAX(Trans_id) Trans_id
              FROM policy
             GROUP BY quote_no
       ) sel ON p.quote_no = sel.quote_no AND p.Trans_id = sel.Trans_id
  WHERE trans_type IN ('quote1','new', 'quote2')
  GROUP BY p.quote_no
```

(The sample data in your question doesn't give a very interesting result set here, because your highest `Trans_id` values apply to boring records.)

Finally, adapt that query to do your presentation. Your presentation involves *pivoting* the rows for each `trans_type` so they appear as columns. That gets done with the `SUM(IF...` pattern.

```
SELECT p.quote_no, 
       SUM(IF(p.trans_type = 'new', p.quoted_premium, 0)) new,
       SUM(IF(p.trans_type = 'quote1', p.quoted_premium, 0)) quote1,
       SUM(IF(p.trans_type = 'quote2', p.quoted_premium, 0)) quote2,
       SUM(p.quoted_premium) GrandSum
  FROM policy p
  JOIN (
             SELECT quote_no, MAX(Trans_id) Trans_id
              FROM policy
             GROUP BY quote_no
       ) sel ON p.quote_no = sel.quote_no AND p.Trans_id = sel.Trans_id
  WHERE trans_type IN ('quote1','new', 'quote2')
  GROUP BY p.quote_no
```

**Pro tip**: SQL is declarative, not procedural. It's a language for declaring what sets of data you need from your tables. So, when designing this stuff think about sets: the set of latest transaction ids, the set of policy rows with the correct transaction types, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot